# How to make sure a task is done before returning from a function?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a decent understanding of how **Async/Await** works in **C#**.

I understand that when the `await` keyword is reached, control is given back to the calling function and that is how asynchronous execution is achieved (if I am wrong here, I would appreciate correction and a better explanation).

However I am not sure as to how I would make sure that an async function has finished executing before returning from a function.

Take the example below:

```
private static async Task<bool> LoadDataIntoLocalAppFile(ZipArchiveEntry entry, string key)
{
    try
    {
        /* SqLiteAsyncConnection is an instance variable in the class that has this function.*/
        string pathToUse = "localDatabase.db"
        if (SqLiteAsyncConnection != null)
        {
            await SqLiteAsyncConnection.CloseAsync()
                .ContinueWith(x => entry.ExtractToFile(pathToUse, true));
        }
        else
        {
            entry.ExtractToFile(pathToUse, true);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Colsole.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, I want to make sure that my `SqLiteAsyncConnection` is closed before I replace the data in the `.db` file with the contents of entry (so that it does not error out). As such I have used `ContinueWith` (if this is wrong I would appreciate some clarification).

But I also want to ensure that `await SqLiteAsyncConnection.CloseAsync().ContinueWith(x => entry.ExtractToFile(pathToUse, true));` finishes its execution before the function returns. That is I want to ensure that this function does not return true inaccurately, and that it does not return true before `await SqLiteAsyncConnection.CloseAsync() .ContinueWith(x => entry.ExtractToFile(pathToUse, true));` finishes its execution.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: When `await` is encountered, execution of the current method stops. The current thread is free to go off and do something else. When the awaited task completes, some thread (maybe the same one, maybe not) resumes executing the method after the `await`.

Comment: @techinquisitor. Nope. When `await` is encountered, the completion of the task being awaited and the that follows the `await` is wrapped in a new task and the current method ends, returning that newly created task.  When the awaited task completes, the newly created one starts (as if there was a `ContinueWith`). The effect of all this is a behavior that looks things stop and then restart - but they don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `ContinueWith` when you have `await` there. You would use `ContinueWith` if you don't use `await`, it can be seen as a type of callback once the parent task has completed/failed.

```cs
await SqLiteAsyncConnection.CloseAsync()
                .ContinueWith(x => entry.ExtractToFile(pathToUse, true));

//can be replaced by

await SqLiteAsyncConnection.CloseAsync();
entry.ExtractToFile(pathToUse, true);
```

When you hit an `await` section in your code, your function isn't done, it doesn't return `true`, it gets suspended in a sense and the control is given back to calling thread. Once all your `await`s have completed in the function, only then does it return the result.

Comment: I initially had my code like this, and it was bugging out (It would seemingly try to execute `entry.ExtractToFile(pathToUse, true)` before `await SqLiteAsyncConnection.CloseAsync()` was done) so I used ContinueWith instead and that fixed it.

Comment: The explanation "Once all your awaits have completed in the function, only then does it return the result" seems to be what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> When the `await` keyword is reached, control is given back to the calling function.

I find this commonly used explanation confusing. In simpler terms, the job of an asynchronous method is to create a `Task`. That's why you call the method, to get a `Task` back. You get this `Task` when the first¹ `await` is reached inside this method. At this point the asynchronous operation has started, and (generally) it has not completed yet. The caller has received the `Task` that represents the asynchronous operation, and can continue doing other things while the operation is in-flight. In some cases the caller has nothing better to do than wait for the completion of the asynchronous operation, in which case you see this pattern:

```
await LoadDataIntoLocalAppFile();
```

Here the caller is itself an asynchronous method. We know it because of the `await` keyword. The code above is equivalent with this:

```
Task task = LoadDataIntoLocalAppFile();
await task;
```

The first line will complete when the first `await` inside the `LoadDataIntoLocalAppFile` is reached. The second line will complete when the last line of code inside the `LoadDataIntoLocalAppFile` has ran.

¹ <sub>To be more precise, the first `await` of a non-completed awaitable.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of async/await is incorrect, just awaiting the asynchronous call is enough:

```
private static async Task<bool> LoadDataIntoLocalAppFile(ZipArchiveEntry entry, string key)
{
    try
    {
        string pathToUse = "localDatabase.db"
        
        await SqLiteAsyncConnection?.CloseAsync();
        entry.ExtractToFile(pathToUse, true);
        
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Colsole.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then call with:

```
await LoadDataIntoLocalAppFile(...
```

Comment: I initially had my code like this, and it was bugging out (It would seemingly try to execute `entry.ExtractToFile(pathToUse, true)` before `await SqLiteAsyncConnection.CloseAsync()` was done) so I used ContinueWith instead and that fixed it.